# Shapefile database structure

Tags: shapefile

I'm a longtime GIS user who's just recently started learning more about data structures, cursors, and search/sort algos. I've used arcpy.mapping's UpdateCursor and the like for years now and didn't think much about how they worked. Recently, one of my assignments was to load a dictionary into a linked list in C - that meant rolling nodes with pointers to the "next" node's address and manually indexing the cursor to search something.

Is the underlying data structure for a shapefile's anything like this - is it implemented using a linked-list-like structure? Or a different data structure entirely? Also, does each row in the shapefile database containing a shape string and some other fields (id, name...) include information (like an address) regarding how to find the "next" or "previous" row?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "database". Which data exactly are you wondering about?

Comment: Have you read the specification http://downloads.esri.com/support/whitepapers/mo_/shapefile.pdf? The dbf part is not explained in details but it s at least almost dBase III.

Comment: Linked-list is a memory-based data structure, more suitable to applications than data storage. *Advanced* data structures is generally the class where file layouts and disk access optimization techniques are taught.

Comment: I'll try to clarify. I've used arcpy.mapping's UpdateCursor and the like for years now and didn't think much about how they worked. Recently, one of my assignments was to load a dictionary into a linked list in C - that meant rolling our own nodes and manually indexing the cursor to search something. Does each row in the shapefile database containing a shape string and some other fields (id, name...) include information (like an address) regarding how to find the "next" or "previous" row?

Comment: Please [Edit] your question to include this clarification. The shapefile specification covers this (in file-based formats, *next* is implicit, and *previous* is exceedingly ugly). Note that applications must form their own linkage between the geometry stored in `.shp` and the other properties stored in `.dbf` since they are only bound by record number.

Comment: @Vince edited for clarity! Can you explain what you mean by "next is implicit"? That is, is the next record stored contiguously to the first in memory? Again, I'm beyond the limits of my knowledge here so any mental model you can provide is much appreciated.

Comment: If you review the specification, it tells you that the file is sequential access with ordered records. While it's possible that the `shx` could skip around randomly, I doubt that would be conforming (and doing so would be exceedingly ugly, and break most readers). Given an open specification and multiple open-source access libraries, everything you need is already available. If you don't understand something in the specification, focus the Question on that.